# How can one solve this differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

We're give the following differential equation:
$$mx''(t)+kx(t)=f(t)$$where $m$ and $k$ are constants and $f(t)$ is a periodic function of period $2L$.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

First, I solved the homogeneous differential equation
$$mx''(t)+kx(t)=0$$
and got the familiar solution
$$x_c(t)=A\cos\bigg(\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{m}}t\bigg)+B\sin\bigg(\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{m}}t\bigg)$$

Then I went to find the particular solution, and since the only given about $f(t)$ is its periodicity, it seemed I have to use Fourier series.

The Fourier expansion of $f(t)$ is 
$$f(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}c_ne^{jn\dfrac{\pi}{L}t}$$
where $j\equiv\sqrt{-1}$ and $c_n$ is a function of $n$. Thus the particular solution has to be of the form 
$$x_p(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}b_ne^{jn\dfrac{\pi}{L}t}$$
where $b_n$ is some other function of $n$.

Calculating the derivatives, then substituting in the equation and solving for $b_n$ I got 
$$b_n=\dfrac{c_n}{k-m\Big(\dfrac{n\pi}{L}\Big)^2}.$$
This solution is okay as long as denominator is different from zero for all $n$. However, if $\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{m}}$ is a multiple of $\dfrac{\pi}{L}$, then there will be some $n$ that will set the denominator to zero, and the particular solution will cease to exist. How to solve the equation in this case?
I tried hard but I couldn't.

Comment: Then you'll have a _resonance solution_ looking like $t\cdot\cos t$ or something.

Comment: We only get this solution if $f(t)$ was sinusoidal, not any periodic function.

Comment: The general solution is $x(t)=\cos(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}t)x(0)+\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}\sin(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}t) x'(0)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{mk}}\int_0^t{\sin\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}(t-s)\right)f(s)ds }$. You need the specific form of $f$ in order to calculate the integral.

Comment: @CTNT Great, can you refer me to the full solution please?

Comment: If $f$ is any periodic function, go expand it to Fourier series and do what you are already doing. All terms will be fine, except maybe one. I told you what to do with that one. Alternatively, do as **CTNT** says. It must end up the same.

Comment: This is a linear system of the form $\dot{y}=Ay+bf(t)$ with state vector $y=[x, x']^T$, $A=\left[\matrix{0 & 1\\-k/m & 0}\right]$ and $b=[0, 1/m]^T$. The solution of this system is $y(t)=e^{At}y(0)+\int_0^t{e^{A(t-s)}bf(s)ds}$. Replacing $e^{At}=\left[\matrix{\cos\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}t\right) & \sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}\sin\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}t\right) \\ - \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\sin\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}t\right)  &  \cos\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}t\right)}\right]$ the response of $x$ is obtained.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution for the case where $\sqrt{k/m}=N\pi/L$ for some integer $N$ iff $f$ is orthogonal in the $L^2$ sense to the homogeneous solutions $\sin(\sqrt{k/m}t)$, $\cos(\sqrt{k/m}t)$. You can see that this is necessary because $mx''+kx$ annihilates these elements. But it's also sufficient, which you can see by constructing the solution using the Fourier series.